# Usercontrol binding passing a value to a property

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

Since Windows8 doesn't have a fleshed out DatePicker yet, I decided to follow some of the examples out there an rolled my own.

By itself it works fine, but now I have dates that I want to pre-populate the DatePicker with.

I created a property in the DatePicker.xaml.cs file below:

```
public DateTime dateVal
{
    get
    {
        return m_dateVal;
    }
    set
    {
        m_dateVal = value;
    }
}
```

Then in my page that is displaying the DatePicker control I tried to bind to the property:

```
<dp:DatePicker Foreground="Black" Height="100" Margin="10,25" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" dateVal="{Binding repairInfoSingle.repairDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

However, stepping into the DatePicker.xaml.cs file the dateVal property was never populated with the date I'm passing into it.

Then I get an error in the output window:

> WinRT information: Failed to assign to property
>   'aG.Common.DatePicker.dateVal'. [Line: 125 Position: 170]

I was hoping to pass the date so then in the constructor I could then set the `SelectedIndex` values by parsing out the Months, Days, and Years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to bind to a property (e.g. use  `DateVal={Binding ...}`) - DateVal can't be a regular CLR property.
You need to change it to a **[DependencyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx)**

So in your example:

```
public DateTime DateVal
{  
    get { return (DateTime) GetValue(DateValProperty); }  
    set { SetValue(DateValProperty, value); } 
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty DateValProperty = 
  DependencyProperty.Register("DateVal", typeof(DateTime), typeof(DatePicker),
  new PropertyMetadata(DateTime.MinValue));
```

Now it should work fine like you wanted:

```
<dp:DatePicker DateVal="{Binding repairInfoSingle.repairDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to bind a value to `dateVal` you will have to make `dateVal` a `DependancyProperty` in the `DatePicker.xaml.cs`

```
    public DateTime DateVal
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(DateValProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DateValProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DateValProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DateVal", typeof(DateTime), typeof(DatePicker), new PropertyMetadata(DateTime.MinValue));
```